# Cake Php 3.0 how to use OAuth php extension

Tags: php, magento, cakephp, oauth

I was trying to use php extension OAuth in a cakephp 3 application for authentication with magento.

The Module was installed in php but when I use it in the application it gives error.

The code written    ([I got it from the magento site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html))

```
 $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, 
                $consumerSecret,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
```

The error got

> Class 'App\Controller\OAuth' not found

Comment: Seriously? You take some random code from another site, throw it somewhere in your code and expect it to work? The error message is as well more than clear. Read about the basics of OOP in php and namespaces. The problem will become obvious to you as well then.

Comment: Sorry I am new to php, I found the error. need to add `use OAuth`

Answer (score 0):

The error was simple, I am new to php and don't know much about its structure

Need to add

```
  use OAuth;
```